# To acces file from Linux server

Tags: web-part, access, file, page-viewer-web-part

We have a Scheduled report that generating from Business Object that is hosted in Linux Server.We required to show this report in share point site.Is there any built in webpart for this. How can we achieve this .

Answer (score 1):

The Page Viewer Web Part can be used to display any file that is accessible via a network path or http address.  It will be located under the "Content" or "Media and Content" category.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But is there any way to hide the explorer bar in the side of the page.